# Need help in writing a SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement like, in a table there are Columns and values like below

```
Emp ID  Address Department  Supervisior ID
1001    Chennai Science     123
1001    Chennai Science     124
1001    Chennai Science     125
1002    Chennai Science     128
1003    Chennai Science     123
1003    Chennai Science     124
1003    Chennai Science     126
1004    Bangalore  Science  129 
1005    Mumbai  Science    130
1005    Mumbai  Science    131
1005    Mumbai  Science    132
```

From the I/p table, i will the prompt for the Supervisior id (i.e Supervisior id is 123). If I prompt , the output of my query should be

```
Emp ID  Address Department  Supervisior ID
1001    Chennai Science 123
1002    Chennai Science 128
1003    Chennai Science 123
1004    Bangalore   Science 129
1005    Mumbai  Science 130
```

The requirement is, from the table if I prompt for Supervisior id 123, I have to pick all the records which has supervisior Id as 123. But the first three records are same, only difference is supervisior id. So I don't want row number two and three.

Also, I want other records which has supervisior id not equal to 123.So i want row number 4 and 8.But the last three rows are same, only difference is supervisior id. From the last three, I want only one row (i.e row number 9 ).

I tried with union query and full outer join. Nothings works for me.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "pick all the records which hav supervisior Id as 123" and "Also I want other record which supervisior id not equal to 123". Surely that's all the records?

Answer (score 0):

Use "group by" & "min" in your query as below.

```
/****** Dataset ****************/
with tabl(Emp_ID, Address, Department, Supervisior_ID) as
 ( select 1001 , 'Chennai', 'Science' ,   123  from dual
   UNION ALL
   select 1001 , 'Chennai', 'Science' ,   124  from dual
   UNION ALL
   select 1001 , 'Chennai', 'Science' ,   125  from dual
   UNION ALL
   select 1002 , 'Chennai', 'Science' ,   128  from dual
   UNION ALL
   select 1003 , 'Chennai', 'Science' ,   123  from dual
   UNION ALL
   select 1003 , 'Chennai', 'Science' ,   124  from dual
   UNION ALL
   select 1003 , 'Chennai', 'Science' ,   126  from dual
   UNION ALL
   select 1004 , 'Bangalore', 'Science' ,   129  from dual
   UNION ALL
   select 1005 , 'Mumbai', 'Science' ,   130  from dual
   UNION ALL
   select 1005 , 'Mumbai', 'Science' ,   131  from dual
   UNION ALL
   select 1005 , 'Mumbai', 'Science' ,   132  from dual )
 /********You Main query goes from here *************/  
select emp_id,Address, Department, min(Supervisior_ID)
 from tabl
 group by emp_id,Address, Department
 order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`MIN` is what you look for.

```
SELECT EMP_ID,
       ADDRESS,
       DEPARTMENT,
       NVL(
            MIN(DECODE(SUPERVISOR_ID,:L_SUPERVISOR_ID,SUPERVISOR_ID)),
            MIN(SUPERVISOR_ID)
           ) AS SUPERVISOR_ID
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY EMP_ID,ADDRESS,DEPARTMENT
ORDER BY EMP_ID,ADDRESS,DEPARTMENT,SUPERVISOR_ID;
```

The trick here is, `MIN(DECODE(SUPERVISOR_ID,:L_SUPERVISOR_ID,SUPERVISOR_ID))`

Which will be `NULL`, when there is no matching ID, so in that case just do `MIN`. `NVL` take care of it.

When there's a matching Supervisor ID in that group, it will be returned right away.